# Как отправить сообщение на канал по его ID?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Я пишу бота для отправки в свои каналы, и не знаю как отправлять смс на определенный канал.

```
bot.send_message(-1455313, 'text')
```

Думал о таком варианте, где -1455313 это ID, но не пробовал.

Comment: Так может стоит попробовать и написать сюда уже результат ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138301/234134

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать отправлять по названию канала. То есть "юзернейм" канала, тот который через @.